# SFML "dyld: Library not loaded" when run without sudo

Tags: macos, rust, sfml, dynamic-linking, dylib

I created a minimal SFML application using [`rust-sfml`](https://crates.io/crates/sfml). I stripped anything that requires loading files from [the pong example](https://github.com/jeremyletang/rust-sfml/blob/master/examples/pong.rs), but just trying to open a window gives this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/executable
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

When run with sudo, the program works properly. I checked the permissions and they looked correct:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/*sfml*
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin   50296  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      26  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.2.4.dylib -> libcsfml-audio.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      24  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.dylib -> libcsfml-audio.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin  163680  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      29  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib -> libcsfml-graphics.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      27  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.dylib -> libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin   67272  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-network.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      28  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-network.2.4.dylib -> libcsfml-network.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      26  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-network.dylib -> libcsfml-network.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin   20256  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-system.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      27  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-system.2.4.dylib -> libcsfml-system.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      25  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-system.dylib -> libcsfml-system.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin   31892  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      27  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.2.4.dylib -> libcsfml-window.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      25  1 Mar  2017 /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.dylib -> libcsfml-window.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin  159060 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-audio.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      25 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-audio.2.4.dylib -> libsfml-audio.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      23 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-audio.dylib -> libsfml-audio.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin  556312 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      28 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib -> libsfml-graphics.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      26 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.dylib -> libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin  162540 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-network.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      27 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-network.2.4.dylib -> libsfml-network.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      25 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-network.dylib -> libsfml-network.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin   81896 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      26 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system.2.4.dylib -> libsfml-system.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      24 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system.dylib -> libsfml-system.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  admin  227128 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      26 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.2.4.dylib -> libsfml-window.2.4.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin      24 10 Feb  2017 /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.dylib -> libsfml-window.2.4.dylib
```

Versions:

- macOS 10.11.6
- Rust `1.26.0-nightly (75af15ee6 2018-03-20)`
- Cargo `1.26.0-nightly (d6c3983fe 2018-03-16)`
- `rust-sfml` (from `Cargo.toml`) `sfml = "0.14"`
- SFML: 2.4.2, dylib

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo "$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"`?
And does it really say "/path/to/executable"? If not, please give the actual path to the executable (of course you can replace your real username). Also take a look here: https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath

Comment: `echo "$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"` gives `/usr/X11/lib:/usr/lib::`. Thanks for the link, it looks promising.

Comment: You could try this: `export $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` and try if the program starts then (run it in the same she’ll where you exported the path; it’s only temporary). If this works, we know it’s a problem with @rpath.

Comment: Yes, running `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` before the executable works. So is the proper fix exporting that change in .bashrc, or giving some argument to linker?